# Android get inflated layout layout_width and layout_height values

Tags: android, layout

In Android, how can I get the values I set **in my XML file** ?

my_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    .....
<RelativeLayout/>
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
View v = ((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.my_layout, null);

//this gave me -1(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT), which is not what I want. I need 300
v.getLayoutParams().width
// same for height, it gives me -1
 v.getLayoutParams().width
```

I do not care about how the View would actually look, I just need the values...

I know I can get the width and height of a view after the measuring is done (onGlobalLayout), but that's NOT what I need. What I need is the values in my XML.

EDIT1: I know v.getWidth() and v.getHeight() works AFTER the `View` is displayed on the screen, they will not work before measuring happens

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html. View has a getWidth() and getHeight() method. check the docs. Check the public methods section

Comment: I specifically say that I know how to get the dimension of a view after measuring... getWidth() and getHeight() at this point will return 0

Comment: Which solution/answer was most helpful for you to solve this problem? I have the same question and am searching for the correct way to do this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is parse your xml layout in order to get some attributes the try some like this:

```
 Resources r = getResources();
    XmlResourceParser parser = r.getLayout(R.layout.your_layout);

    int state = 0;
    do {
        try {
            state = parser.next();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            //here get the attributes you want..., with AttributeSet for example
            }
        }
    } while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
```

Comment: this returns the value of the measured dimension of the view... not the specific value i assigned in my XML

Answer (score 2):

instead of doing this:

```
View v = ((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

do this:

```
View v = ((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
        R.layout.my_layout, parentView,false);
```

this sets the parent view instead of using null

for more information see this:  http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
int width = v.getWidth();
    int height = v.getHeight();
```

hope this helps

Comment: this returns the value of the measured dimension of the view... not the specific value i assigned in my XML

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `getLayoutParams().width` and `getLayoutParams().height`? Try to do that  on `onCreateView()`, it's working as intended on my end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b= (Button) yourView.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id); 
System.out.println("b.getMeasuredHeight()= "+b.getMeasuredHeight()); 
System.out.println("b.getMeasuredWidth()+ "+ b.getMeasuredWidth());
```